# image_tag inside link_to => undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for "auth/facebook":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I'm missing a little something here ... the it's a simple image inside a link. The code :

```
<%= link_to image_tag "facebook.png", "auth/facebook" %>
```

The error is : `undefined method 'symbolize_keys!' for "auth/facebook":String`

What'd I do wrong here ?

Comment: 1000k views ? Time to upvote guys.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because you're passing the args to the wrong methods:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag ("facebook.png", "auth/facebook")) %>
```

Oh, why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Right - I feel stupid. FYI it for facebook "openid", with OmniAuth plugin.

Comment: perfect thank you. Even if the syntax is bad today. Should be: link_to (image_tag ("facebook.png"), "auth/facebook")